# drupal 7 get file path

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

I have a drupal form of type file, I want to use this form to upload a photo under the default/files/backgroudimage and than I get the uploaded file path and use it as a backgroud image for some javascript file. my question is I used both $file->uri and file_create_url($file->uri)

```
$file = file_load($form_state['values']['Background_image']);
         //  // Change status to permanent.
        $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
```

for the first `$url1=$file->uri;` gave me this result (relative path) `public://backgroundimage/image.jpg`
for the second `$url2=file_create_url($file->uri);` gave me full path:`http://localhost:8080/SiteName/sites/default/files/backgroundimage/image.jpg`
In my javascript I will get the path and use it to set a backgroud image:

```
document.getElementById('myElement').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myUrl+')';
```

question is $myUrl how it supposed to be like? is it default/files/backgroundimage/image.jpg or public://backgroundimage/image.jpg ...?

Answer (score 0):

your css should be in /sites/all/themes/xxx, so you can't access images from there by

/default/files/backgroundimage/image.jpg

public://background points to /sites/default/files/ if correctly configured but you can not use uri in js

you should use a document root relative path instead:

/sites/default/files/backgroundimage/image.jpg

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?